# vbscript cannot find batch file stored in google drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to run the following C:\users\jdoe\google drive\bin\script.vbs script on Windows 7:

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\users\jdoe\google drive\bin\run.bat", 0, True
```

But I always get the error:

```
---------------------------
Windows Script Host
---------------------------
Script: C:\Users\jdoe\Google Drive\bin\script.vbs
Line:1
Char:   1
Error:  The system cannot find the file specified. 
Code:   80070002
Source:     (null)

---------------------------

OK   
---------------------------
```

When I change the path of my run.bat file to c:\run.bat and of course move the run.bat file to c:\, the script.vbs runs without problems.

Any way to get my scripts stored in google drive to run? I have the same issue when using the local group policy editor to select a shutdown or logon/logoff script that is stored in google drive...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try running the script as an administrator?  Windows does some weird redirection things with wscript based on the UAC permissions.

Answer (score 4):

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "C:\users\jdoe\google drive\bin\run.bat", 0, True
                                   ^..................^ ^...............^
                                   command to run        arguments
```

You need to quote the the command to avoid problems with spaces

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """C:\users\jdoe\google drive\bin\run.bat""", 0, True
```

Remember that a double quote inside a string needs to be escaped, writting two double quotes where one must be included.

Answer (score 1):

**To avoid problems with spaces** : you must try like this way to get rid of this error that comes from spaces in the path of your application:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Application
Application = "C:\users\jdoe\google drive\bin\run.bat"
Call RunThis(Application)
'*********************************************************************************
Sub RunThis(Application)
    Dim Ws,Result
    Set Ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Result = Ws.Run(DblQuote(Application),0,True)
End Sub
'*********************************************************************************
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'*********************************************************************************
```